# Exception in TransactionScope

Tags: c#, .net, transactions

I get the following exception when I run the following code at line

```
EntityScope<TQFormContext>.CurrentObjectContext.SaveChanges();
```

"The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements."

```
[TestMethod()]
    public void TransactionTest()
    {
        using (TransactionScope tc = new TransactionScope())
        {

            var u1 =  EntityScope<TQFormContext>.CurrentObjectContext.ASUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == 1);

            var u2 = PersistenceManager.GetById<TQ.Business.PO.Administration.UserPO>(2);
            u1.MiddleInitial = "1";
            u2.MiddleInitial = "1";

            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("Update asusers set middleinitial='1' where userid=3", sqlConn);
                sqlConn.Open();
                sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            PersistenceManager.SaveOrUpdate(u2);
            EntityScope<TQFormContext>.CurrentObjectContext.SaveChanges();

         //   throw new Exception("Blah");
            tc.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The default Transaction Scope option is Required which will make your new TransactionScope join an existing ambient transacton.  So I think if you pass the RequiresNew Transaction Scope option in your constructor this should work.